# Select next option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I'm trying to create a button that can select next option.

So, i have a select (id=selectionChamp) with several options, an input next (id=fieldNext), and i try to do that :

```
$('#fieldNext').click(function() {
    $('#selectionChamp option:selected', 'select').removeAttr('selected')
          .next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');

    alert($('#selectionChamp option:selected').val());      
});
```

But I can not select the next option.. Thanks !

Comment: Are you loading DOM on page load ?

Comment: means are you using that code in ready function ?

Comment: Use latest version of jquery and `on` method for event binding.

Comment: Yes, in ready function. But it's ok i have my answer ^^

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$('#fieldNext').click(function() {
    $('#selectionChamp option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');

    alert($('#selectionChamp').val());      
});
```

Better answer by @VisioN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11556661/1533609

Comment: Needs to also deselect current option e.g. `$('#selectionChamp option:selected').attr('selected', false);`

Comment: @anthonygore is right. If you do not clear this for the current version of Safari, it will yield a null value and the select menu will stay sitting on the original value.

Comment: This did not worked for me without `.trigger('change')`

Comment: @teewuane I guess I'll take your word, but it doesn't make any sense. Once you deselect, it would seem $('#selectionChamp option:selected') would return the first item in the drop down. Seems like VisioN's answer is more sane.

Comment: @sg_man yes. His answer is better. I answered it 2 minutes earlier 7 years ago so it is accepted but his answer is better. no doubt

Answer (score 22):

```
$("#fieldNext").click(function() {
    $("#selectionChamp > option:selected")
        .prop("selected", false)
        .next()
        .prop("selected", true);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/w9kcd/1/

Comment: Your example does not cycle thru elements... Just stops at last one.

Comment: @AleksandarPavić Why should it?

Comment: sorry you are right, it's not required to cycle in original request, however here is improved answer which cycles and triggers change event, in jQuery manner, after all it's about providing best answers to people http://jsfiddle.net/acosonic/2cg9t17j/3/

Answer (score 14):

Pretty simple without jQuery too. This one will loop around to the first option once the last is reached:

```
function nextOpt() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('selectionChamp');
  var i = sel.selectedIndex;
  sel.options[++i%sel.options.length].selected = true;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('fieldNext').onclick = nextOpt;
}
```

Some test markup:

```
<button id="fieldNext">Select next</button>
<select id="selectionChamp">
 <option>0
 <option>1
 <option>2
</select>
```

Comment: Long live RobG!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
  $('#button').on('click', function(){
    var selected_element = $('#selectionChamp option:selected');
    selected_element.removeAttr('selected');
    selected_element.next().attr('selected', 'selected');

    $('#selectionChamp').val(selected_element.next().val());

  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ejunoz/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

I would expect such button to loop thru options, and also to trigger change event. Here is possible solution for that:

```
$("#fieldNext").click(function() {
  if ($('#selectionChamp option:selected').next().length > 0) 
    $('#selectionChamp option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
  else $('#selectionChamp option').first().attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
});
```

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acosonic/2cg9t17j/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fieldNext').click(function() {
$('#selectionChamp option:selected').removeAttr('selected')
      .next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');

alert($('#selectionChamp option:selected').val());      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fieldNext").on("click",function(){
            $optionSelected = $("#selectionChamp > option:selected");
            $optionSelected.removeAttr("selected");
            $optionSelected.next("option").attr("selected","selected");       
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions don't work in case there are optiongroup elements in addition to option elements. In that case, this seems to work:

```
var options = $("#selectionChamp option");
var i = options.index(options.filter(":selected"));
if (i >= 0 && i < options.length - 1) {
    options.eq(i+1).prop("selected", true);
}
```

(You may think that the expression for `i` could also be written as `options.index(":selected")`, but that doesn't always work. I don't know why, an explanation would be welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

With simple javascript

```html
<select id="color">
  <option>red
  <option>blue
  <option>green
</select>

<button onclick="(color.selectedOptions[0].nextElementSibling || color.options[0]).selected = true">Select next</button>
```