# Value in Dropdown 1 selects next value in Dropdown 2

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, plugins

I'm building a custom local directory/information/community plugin for WordPress. One of the features I'm adding is a "Create an Event" form. Title, host, date, time, location, etc. Right now, I have the start dates automatically change the end dates to be the same. So for the MM-DD-YYY, Dropdown 1(DD1) will automatically change Dropdown 2(DD2) so they are the same. (e.g. March 1, 2019.) What I'm wanting to do for the Start and End times (HH:MM), is set the value in DD2 to be the next one from DD1. (e.g. Start time of 07:00 via DD1; DD2 End Time automatically set to 08:00.) The value in DD1 needs to be DD1+1 in DD2 (e.g. DD1 is 8; DD2 is 9. DD1 is 12; DD2 is 1. DD1 is 2; DD2 is 3.) This is all done prior to being submitted so it's an easy user experience and allows for faster creation.

I got help with setting two different dropdowns with the same values from here: [Fill second dropdown with the same value as the first dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519817/fill-second-dropdown-with-the-same-value-as-the-first-dropdown)

I've also referred to [Select next option with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556557/select-next-option-with-jquery) for selecting the next value, but it only chooses the next entire value for each `change`. I've tried `next()`, `trigger('change')`, `val()`, and who knows what else.

And I've also looked at many other SE questions and Google'd articles, but still not finding the solution I'm looking. And admittedly, my jQuery/JavaScript knowledge is extremely limited so I'm sure that isn't helping any either.

HTML

```
<select name="dropdown" id="drop">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="some" id="two">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#drop').change(function() {
    var value = $('#drop option:selected').text();

    $("#two option:selected" ).text(value);
});
```

Here's my JSFiddle I've been playing with. http://jsfiddle.net/o5fzq74a/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with this script is - if you select "3" in the first select, then this will be the second select:

```
<select name="some" id="two">
    <option value="1">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

You change the text of the first option (value 1). Do you want this or do you want to set the "selected" attribute to value 3?

Then you should:

```
$("#two").val(3).change();
```

And you could increment this "3" with +1

Edit:

Here is a working code:

```
$('#drop').change(function() {
    var value = parseInt($('#drop option:selected').text());

    $("#two").val(value + 1).change();

});
```

Your next project is: check if var value is 23 and set it 0 ;-)

Edit 2:
it works "out of the box" when the last value is selected in the first select:
http://jsfiddle.net/7t24jbvk/

Regards Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll tinker with it when I get a free moment. If I increment +1, when the value reaches 12 - because 1, 2, 3, 4.....12 HH - will that start at 1 again or do I need to make an if-else statement?

Comment: I updated my answer ;-). Yes, you should check if it is 12 (or 23, depends on your time) and set it to 1 or 0.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7t24jbvk/